# Unexpected results using LOOKUP or VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm attempting to perform a `LOOKUP` to obtain the correct abbreviation for a given string however getting some unexpected results.

Given the table:

```
   _______________A__________________B____
1 | System Software Specification |SSS
2 | System Test Specification     |STS
3 | System Test Report            |STSREP
```

Entering the equation:

```
=LOOKUP(A3,A1:A3,B1:B3)
```

or:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,A1:B3,2)
```

Returns the results `SSS` instead of my expected `STSREP`.

However given:

```
   _______________A__________________B____
1 | System Software Specification |SSS
2 | System Test                   |STS
3 | System Test Report            |STSREP
```

It works as expected, can anyone explain why this is, and ideally, how to fix it?

Comment: use `,FALSE` as the forth criterion in the VLOOKUP.

Comment: @ScottCraner Great, that works, is there any way to fix it for `LOOKUP` it's a legacy sheet and I'd prefer for it to stay as similar to how it is now as possible

Comment: Further to @ScottCraner's solution, failing to use FALSE as the optional 4th parameter **absolutely requires** that the data in the lookup column (column A) be sorted. *System Test* is greater then *System Software Specification* but it is **not** less than *System Test Report*. LOOKUP has no parameter for an absolute non-sorted match so the data **has** to be sorted.

Comment: Try sorting the data on column A.  LOOKUP requires the data to be sorted.

Comment: @ScottCraner ah, yes, there is a remark in the sheet which says that column A should be sorted however it appears the last person to use it didn't follow that step, I'll pass this on, if you'd like to post both of your comments as an answer I'd happily accept. Also thanks to Jeeped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @ScottCraner and @Jeeped the problem was that the column the `LOOKUP` was being performed on was not properly sorted following additions being made and sorting the table by that column resolved the issue.

As an alternative, had `VLOOKUP` been used `FALSE` could be passed as a 4th parameter in order to obtain the same results.